# facing unconstrained type parameter issue

Tags: rust, types, traits, generics

I'm using fresh node template and trying to implement below code:

```rust
#[pallet::storage]
    pub type Author<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, sr25519::Public, OptionQuery>;
```

```rust
pub struct DataProvider;

impl<T: Config> DataProvider {
    fn details() -> T::AccountId {
        Author::<T>::get().map(|a| a.into())
    }
}
```

But getting this error:

```
impl<T: Config> DataProvider {
     ^ unconstrained type parameter
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to constrain the struct with generic phantom type.

```rs
pub struct DataProvider<T>(sp_std::marker::PhantomData<T>);

impl<T: Config> DataProvider<T> {
    fn details() -> T::AccountId {
        Author::<T>::get().map(|a| a.into())
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah worked!, But why we need to put phantom type? and why we get unconstrained error?